# Kivy ids changing by using strings not working

Tags: python, kivy

I have a ton of different labels that are going to have different numbers on them. I'm creating a running app where you write down how much you run each day. But for some reason doing it dynamically like below isn't working. Do I need to create some sort of id object?

```
def mileageinput(self, mileagevalue):
    global curmileage
    global runs
    try:
        curmileage = float(mileagevalue)
        runs[activeday] = curmileage
        calendar = self.manager.get_screen('calendar')
        label = "mileagerun" + str(activeday)
        print(label)

        # Changing the identifier like this isn't working:
        # calendar.ids.label.text = str(curmileage) + " miles"
        
        # This works, but I have tons of different labels and I want it
        # to work dynamically:
        calendar.ids.mileagerun2.text = str(curmileage) + " miles"
    except:
        curmileage = 0
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. If not, do you need further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Your commented-out line is trying to access an `id` *named* `label`, but you want to access the `id` whose name is the value of the variable `label`.

`ids` can be accessed by dot notation or with an index in brackets -- that is, `ids.foo` is the same thing as `ids['foo']`, and in this case the latter is easier to work with it. Try this:

```py
calendar.ids[label].text = str(curmileage) + " miles"
```

(Note that this is `ids[label]`, NOT `ids['label']`. The latter would be equivalent to your current code.)

---

For completeness's sake, here's one more way to do it. Kivy intentionally makes `ids` available in both ways for your convenience. But what if you were working with something else, that is only available as attributes, and not as indices? Suppose that, after the code below, you want to somehow retrieve the value of `menu.spam` dynamically, using the value of `item`.

```py
menu = object()
menu.spam = False
menu.eggs = True

item = 'spam'
```

The way to do this is with a builtin function, `getattr`:

```py
print(getattr(menu, item))
>>> False
```

Thus, your code could also use:

```py
getattr(calendar.ids, label).text = str(curmileage) + " miles"
```

In this case the first option is, I think, much more readable, but `getattr` is good to know about in other, similar cases.

---

And one final note: you might enjoy trying out [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), which can make it much more convenient to insert variables into strings. For instance, `str(curmileage) + " miles"` could instead be:

```py
f"{curmileage} miles"
```

It handles turning things into strings for you automatically, and you can insert as many variables as you need all into the same string.